# Analysis Services As a service with large amount of data

Tags: azure, ssas, ssas-tabular

We have a large amount of data stored on hadoop (with multiple servers on Azure), we will clean and store our data into a datamart  (star schema) on hadoop.
Our goal is to provide this data to users in a self service mode.

For that we already have a good knowledge of SSAS (multidim and tabular installed on premise), but we never use it on that kind of volumetry **(7 billions of rows)**
SSAS as a service is completly new for us, and we don't really know if it will the same as we know.

Do you know if **Analysis Services as a service** (provided on Azure plateform) will be able to store, process and provide us our data?
Do you know or did you meet some limitations?

Thank you very much for your support

Comment: Number of rows doesn't matter as much. What is the size of the data raw and uncompressed?

Comment: Hi Josh, 

we should have 10 foreign key store as sha key (10 * 20 bytes) + some measures. 

One row could have a size of 300 bytes. 

If my calculation is not bad it should be equal to 2 Terabyte. 

Did anyone already experiment that with ssas as a service? 

Thank you, 
Arnaud

Comment: I am aware of customers with solutions that size or larger. Just remember, you will need to fit the data in memory after it is compressed.